# RPG Stats Issue

Tags: c++

I'm having a bit of an issue with my RPG stats code. I want people to use 6 basic stats (strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, and charisma) that have a minimum value of 10. When creating the character, I'd like them to have 15 points to use, and in my code, it all works fine, unless you run out of points to place before you get to the last stat. Let's say you put all 15 points into strength. The display says that you'll have 25 strength, 32478493 dexterity, -42734627 constitution, -1 intelligence, etc. (these aren't exact number, just examples of what it looks like.) Here's the code.

CharCreate.h

```
#ifndef CharCreate_H
#define CharCreate_H
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int charcreate(){

      fstream file;

      char gender, choice;
      string name, dummy;
      int points;
      int str, dex, con, intel, wis, cha;
      float level;
      double experience;


      level = 1;
      experience = 0;

      ofstream myFile;
      myFile.open ("T:\\character.txt");

      system("color 2");
      cout << "Welcome to the character creator." << endl;
      genderchoice:cout << "First, are you male or female? (M/F)" << endl;
      cin >> gender;
      system("cls");

      if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm'){
                 cout << "You're male? (Y/N)" << endl;
                 cin >> choice;
                 system("cls");
                          if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'){
                                    cout << "Great!" << endl;
                                    goto name;
                          } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                     goto genderchoice;
                          }
      } else if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f'){
                cout << "You're female? (Y/N)" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                system("cls");
                         if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'){
                                     cout << "Great!" << endl;
                                     goto name;
                          } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                     goto genderchoice;
                          }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
 name:system("cls");
      system("color 3");
      cout << "What is your name, traveler?" <<endl;
      getline(cin,dummy);
      getline(cin, name);
      cout << "" << endl;
      cout << "Your name is " << name << "? (Y/N)" << endl;
      cin >> choice;

          if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'){
                     system("cls");
                     cout << "Greetings, " << name << "!" << endl;
          } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                     system("cls");
                     cout << "You must provide your name, stranger."  << endl;
                     goto name;
          }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stats:system("cls");
      system("color 4");
      cout << "You have 6 stats to deal with in this game, and 15 points" << endl;
      cout << "to allocate between them all." << endl;
      cout << "These are: Strength (STR), Dexterity (DEX), Constitution (CON)," << endl;
      cout << "Intelligence (INT), Wisdom (WIS), and Charisma (CHA)." << endl;
      cout << "Continue: C" << endl;
      cout << "Help: H" << endl;
      cin >> choice;

      if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c'){

          attrib:points = 15;

             str:cout << "You have 10 Strength. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> str;
                 points = points - str;
                        if (str > points > 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                str = str - points;
                                goto str;
                        } else if (str == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto str;
                        } else if (str < points){
                               goto dex;
                        }
                 }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 str = str + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << str << " Strength" << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

             dex:cout << "You have 10 Dexterity. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> dex;
                 points = points - dex;
                        if (dex > points > 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                dex = dex - points;
                                goto dex;
                        } else if (dex == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto dex;
                        } else if (dex < points){
                               goto con;
                        }
                 }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 dex = dex + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << dex << " Dexterity" << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

             con:cout << "You have 10 Constitution. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> con;
                 points = points - con;
                        if (con > points > 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                con = con - points;
                                goto con;
                        } else if (con == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto con;
                        } else if (con < points){
                               goto intel;
                        }
                 }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 con = con + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << con << " Constitution" << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

           intel:cout << "You have 10 Intelligence. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> intel;
                 points = points - intel;
                  if (intel > points > 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                intel = intel - points;
                                goto intel;
                        } else if (intel == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto intel;
                        } else if (intel < points){
                               goto wis;
                        }
                  }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 intel = intel + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << intel << " Intelligence" << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

             wis:cout << "You have 10 Wisdom. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> wis;
                 points = points - wis;
                  if (wis > points > 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                wis = wis - points;
                                goto wis;
                        } else if (wis == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto wis;
                        } else if (con < points){
                               goto cha;
                        }
                  }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 wis = wis + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << wis << " Wisdom" << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

             cha:cout << "You have 10 Charisma. How many more points do you wish to add?" << endl;
                 cin >> cha;
                 points = points - cha;
                  if (cha > points == 15){
                                cout << "Not enough points!" << endl;
                                cha = cha - points;
                                goto cha;
                        } else if (cha == points){
                                cout << "Are you sure you want to put all of your points here?" << endl;
                                cin >> choice;
                                    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
                                               goto fin;
                                    } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
                                               goto cha;
                        } else if (con < points){
                               goto fin;
                        }
                  }
                 cout << "Remaining points: " << points;
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 cha = cha + 10;
                 cout << "You have " << cha << " Charisma." << endl;
                 system("pause");
                 system("cls");

             fin:cout << "Your stats are:" << endl;
                 cout << "Strength: " << str << endl;
                 cout << "Dexterity: " << dex << endl;
                 cout << "Constitution: " << con << endl;
                 cout << "Intelligence: " << intel << endl;
                 cout << "Wisdom: " << wis << endl;
                 cout << "Charisma: " << cha << endl;
                 cout << "Are these correct? (Y/N)" << endl;
                 cin >> choice;
                 cout << "" << endl;

                  if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'){
                   cout << "Congratulations, you have successfully finished your character." << endl;
                  } else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
                    goto attrib;
                  }
      } else if (choice == 'H' || choice == 'h'){
             cout << "Strength is how easily you can crush a tomato." << endl;
             cout << "Dexterity is how easily you can handle a tomato with your hands." << endl;
             cout << "Constitution is how easily you can eat a bad tomato." << endl;
             cout << "Intelligence is knowing that tomato is a fruit." << endl;
             cout << "Wisdom is not putting tomato in a fruit salad." << endl;
             cout << "Charisma is selling a tomato-based fruit salad." << endl;
             system("pause");
             goto stats;
      }

          myFile << "Name: " << name << "\n";
          myFile << "Gender: " << gender << "\n";
          myFile << "\n";
          myFile << "Level: " << level << "\n";
          myFile << "Experience: " << experience << "\n";
          myFile << "\n";
          myFile << "Strength: " << str << "\n";
          myFile << "Dexterity: " << dex << "\n";
          myFile << "Constitution: " << con << "\n";
          myFile << "Intelligence: " << intel << "\n";
          myFile << "Wisdom: " << wis << "\n";
          myFile << "Charisma: " << cha << "\n";
   myFile.close();      
}              
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "CharCreate.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    charcreate();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How would I correct the problem of the numbers going haywire after running out of points? If it helps, I'm running Bloodshed Dev C++ as the compiler because that's the one we have to use at college.

Comment: try initializing your variables to 10

Answer (score 1):

In C++ if you don't set a value to a variable, it will contain whatever random data happens to be there at the time. You are going to want to initialize each stat to 10 (or some sane default value) at the start.

Comment: The random value can be found in the variable on stack and that variable is most likely of primitive type (without any constructor). Otherwise, static and global primitive variables are all zeroed by default and the ones with constructors usually initialized by default regardless the context.